# What is Podfile.lock in our Xcode projects and why is it used?

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, objectmapper

I am a beginner in using pods in Xcode projects. I have been confused by Podfile.lock.  I want to update a framework "OBJECTMAPPER" to 2.0 to make it compatible with Swift 3. However it doesn't.

[image: 1]

Why doesn't it update to the latest version (2.0)? Does it have anything to do with Podfile.lock? Which is as follows ->

[image: 2]

and why is it used?

---

Update: The Podfile

[image: 3]

Comment: See the documentation: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/using-cocoapods.html#what-is-podfilelock  To get more help here, please show the content of your Podfile

Comment: i have edited the post

Comment: `Podfile.lock` is a [YAML](https://yaml.org) file as an assistant of `Podfile`.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone is wondering, I did the same 2 years ago.

When you install a library with cocoapods a podlock will be generated against it with the version of the library that is installed. For example suppose you have library named "XX" and you install the latest version of "XX", e.g 2.0.0, then it will be installed and podfile.lock will have an entry for the version (XX - (2.0.0)).

Suppose if a new version is released of that library and you do not want to update our project, then use pod install. This will only install any new libraries or updates that appear in the podfile and will not change the existing version of this library.

This prevents any changes to the library from affecting the current project.

If you want to update "XX" to a newer version in the future, use pod update for that library.

Answer (score 2):

pod install will not update ObjectMapper to the latest version because there is no reason for it to do so. ObjectMapper is included as a dependency to UberRides and version 1.5.0 satisfies the requirement which is 1 or above.

In order to force an update you can add ObjectMapper to the podfile with the required version, e.g.

```
pod 'ObjectMapper', '2.0'
```

Comment: i did pod Update ... not pod install